# Forward Declaration Stalls App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I was having issues where I had circular dependencies and so I am trying to implement forward declaration. I have three classes (logger, api, helpers), all of which are singleton objects. I have one controller class (globalclass), that has properties linking to the three classes.

Here is my code:

includes.h:

```
#import "globalclass.h"
#import "logger.h"
#import "api.h"
#import "helpers.h"
```

globalclass.h:

```
@class logger
@class api
@class helpers

@interface globalclass : NSObject

+ (id) sharedGlobal;

- (id) init;

...

@property (nonatomic, strong) logger *log;
@property (nonatomic, strong) api *remote;
@property (nonatmoic, strong) helpers *utils;

...
```

logger/api/helpers.h templates:

```
@class globalclass

@interface logger : NSObject

+ (id) sharedLogger;

- (id) init;

...

@property (nonatomic, strong) globalclass *gc;

...
```

globalclass.m:

```
#import "includes.h"

@implementation globalclass

/*
 * Singleton Class
 */
+ (id) sharedGlobal
{
    static globalclass *sharedGlobalClass = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedGlobalClass = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedGlobalClass;
}

/*
 * Init
 */
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // Logging
    self.logger = [logger sharedLogger];

    ...

    return self;
}
```

logger/api/helpers.m template:

```
#import "includes.h"

@implementation logger

/*
 * Singleton Class
 */
+ (id) sharedLogger
{
    static logger *sharedLog = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedLog = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedLog;
}

/*
 * Init
 */
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // Global Class
    self.gc = [GlobalClass sharedGlobal];

    ...

    return self;
}
```

Then, in my AppDelegate, I have a property to the global class and am doing this:

> > self.gc = [GlobalClass sharedGlobal];

However, it seems that everytime I boot up my app, it stalls and is automatically terminated because it takes too long to boot up.

Am I thinking about forward globals incorrectly?

The app builds fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: At a glance, I think you have a deadlock.

Comment: Yeah, from some debugging I am thinking that the globalclass cant finish its init because when it starts to init the logger, it contains a globalclass init and continues this cycle.

Comment: Also, I would ask if there is a good reason for all of these classes to be singletons? For example, perhaps it makes more sense for one of the singleton objects to "own" an instance of one of the other classes, and that other class is no longer a singleton. Or you could break up one of the singleton classes into more granular sets of responsibilities and distribute its code among other classes. Or use categories. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a deadlock, because the dispatch_once block in `sharedGlobal` is (via the global class init) invoking `sharedLogger`, which itself is invoking `sharedGlobal` (via the logger class init).

Since everything is singletons, there are a few approaches you could take to avoid this issue. Here are two:

A. Replace any `self.log` usages in the global class with `[logger sharedLogger]`, and replace any `self.gc` usages in the logger class with `[globalclass sharedGlobal]`. You can get rid of these properties entirely. `dispatch_once` is very fast after the first invocation, so performance is not a reason to store reference to singletons as properties (though you could conceivably have other reasons)

B. Keep the `log` and `gc` properties, but make them readonly properties with custom getters:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) globalclass *gc;
// implementation:
- (globalclass *)gc
{
    return [globalclass sharedGlobal];
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) logger *log;
// implementation:
- (logger *)log
{
    return [logger sharedLogger];
}
```

Personally I would choose A.

Both of these alternatives eliminate any references to the singleton accessors from the init methods, which gets rid of the deadlock.